# Struggling to understand file pointers?

Tags: c, if-statement, file-pointer

Main description of the problem below, where it happens. But simply, I cannot figure out why I get error messages after asking

```
if (outf!=NULL){
    printf("Output file already exists, overwrite (y/n):");
    scanf("%c",yn);
}
```

Where outf is a file pointer to an existing file. Please read description halfway through code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

/* Declare file pointer */
    FILE *inf;
    FILE *outf;

    int linenumber,linecounter=0,linepresent;
    char filename[21];
    char detail[21];
    char linedetail[21];
    char outfilename[21];
    char letter,yn='y';
    int position;

/*INPUT DETAILS Ask user for file name and line number*/

    printf("Please enter an input filename and a linenumber: ");
//scan filename to char string and line number to int variable
    scanf("%s %i",&filename,&linenumber);

/*OUTPUT DETAILS Ask user for file name, letter & position, etc*/
    printf("Please enter an output filename, a letter and a position:");    
    scanf("%s %c %i",&outfilename,&letter,&position);

/* Open file for reading */
    inf=fopen (filename,"r");
    outf=fopen(outfilename,"r");
/*check that file exists*/
    if (inf!=NULL) {
```

Up until here everything works fine!
Then I try to find out if the outf file already exists. If outf points to an existing file, it DOES print "Output file already exists, overwrite (y/n):"

HOWEVER, as soon as it prints this I get error windows opening! This is probably an extremely rookie mistake - I'm still learning C. If there is no such file the program completes normally and bypasses the if statement okay.

```
        if (outf!=NULL){
            printf("Output file already exists, overwrite (y/n):");
            scanf("%c",yn);
        }
        if (yn=='y'){
    /*keep reading to end of file*/
            while (feof(inf)==0) {
                linecounter++;
    /*read each line and store the line number in detail[WORDS GO HERE]*/
                fscanf (inf,"%s", &detail);
    /*If we reach the line selected by the user*/
                if (linecounter==linenumber){
                    strcpy(linedetail,detail);
                    linepresent=1;
                }
            }
            if (linepresent==0) {
                printf("File only contains %i lines",linecounter);
            }
        } else {
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Input file not found");
    }

printf("%s",linedetail);

/* close the file */

    fclose(inf);
    fclose(outf);

    return (0);

}
```

Comment: Do not forget the `&`: `scanf("%c", &yn)`

Comment: If you found the offending line...why didn't you just try a much simpler program that said only `int main() { char yn = 'y'; scanf("%c", yn); return 0; }`...and when that crashed post just that?  :-/  *(Something to consider for next time, that it's best when questions are reduced to the minimal case that produces the error with everything else taken out.)*

Comment: thanks, i do need to refine my questioning technique! cheers for everyones patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, already mentioned problems: You're opening the output file in reading mode. To open it for writing:

```
outf=fopen(outfilename,"w");  /* Note the "w". */
```

Also, scanf() accepts pointers to variables, not their values, so if you write `scanf("%c", yn);`, you will give scanf the character `y` as a pointer, which is nonsense. You need to do it like this: `scanf("%c", &yn);`.

Even if you fix these, however, your program won't do what you expect. If the file you're trying to open for writing doesn't exist, `fopen()` won't return NULL, it will create a new file. Your code will *always* overwrite the output file if it exists. NULL is returned only if `fopen` couldn't open/create the file (e.g. you didn't have the permissions to do it), and you should handle it like this:

```
outf=fopen(outfilename, "w");
if(outf == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to open output file: ");
    fclose(inf);  /* Don't leave files opened. It's bad form. */
    exit(1);
}
/* Open succeeded, do your stuff here. */
```

Note that no `else` block is needed after the `if`, because `exit()` ends the program immediately.

Also, there is no such thing as a "pointer to a file". FILE is just a structure that represents an open file.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/

You are open the output file with the read flag. Try changing it to "w".

```
outf=fopen(outfilename,"w");
```

Although it is worth noting writing to a file opened with "w" will whack the old file. use "a" to append to the file.

Comment: It seems to me that OP intends to first check if the file exists by opening it in read mode first. If a null is returned, file is assumed absent. This is not always correct, since lack of permissions to read an existing file could also return null. stat() library function is perhaps a better choice.

Comment: @Gowtham: I think the OP thinks that opening the *output file* will return NULL if it doesn't exist. Unless he just confused the variables in the `if` condition...

Comment: @Staven You're spot on, I am trying to detect whether the output file already exists. If it does exist the user will then have the option to overwrite it or not. If it doesn't exist then I was intending to fclose and create it in "write" mode. I am having trouble in detecting whether it exists or not. How should I go about this?

Comment: @user1083734 AFAIK there is no way to do that right without using OS-specific functions. You can try to open the *output* file for *reading*, and if it fails, it means it doesn't exist (or it failed for other reasons). If you want more details, make a new question.

Comment: The trouble is, I don't want to overwrite the file immediately, I want to detect whether it exists and then give the option to overwrite y/n!

Comment: @user1083734 Opening the file for *reading* (`"r"`) won't overwrite the file. But, as I've said, you should open a new question. SO isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the address of `yn` to `scanf` function.

`scanf("%c", &yn);`